# How do I execute some code after Symfony3/Doctrine loads data from my database?

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony

I'm coming from a Kohana background and have asked a couple of questions pertaining an issue I'm having and need to find out how to get this done. I am VERY new to Symfony and Doctrine and love learning new frameworks and correct ways to code. However I'm finding Doctrine ORM frustrating to use yet powerful.

So here is my basic issue and I'll try to be brief. I have a `products` table and a `products_images` table. By following the tutorial for Symfony I am already able to create Entities for both and map the relationships, generate getters and setters, create Repositories, and the whole bit. But here is where it gets sticky...

The `product_images` table only contains the name of the image, not the path, which I will obviously need if I am going to construct and useful href in my html. The products table was populated with products by crawling over the web and obtaining them in that method and as a requirement by the persons that are having me write their website, I am required to keep the images separated into directories that represent where they were crawled from. The location of the images has been changing often so I DO NOT want to store the path in the database.

So to keep my question simple what I need to do, somehow, some way, is to write some logic that examines where the image was crawled from and then construct a path string to pass along to my twig template and then append the image name...all in order to create a valid image tag or href.

My last attempt to find a solution for this was to modify the getter for the image name in the Entity but since I am using `createQueryBuilder()` to perform some DQL, it appears the getters aren't being used and now I have nothing to go on. I cannot find any documentation on the official Doctrine website that helps me get around this issue and I just need to know how to overcome this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Let's skip Doctrine for a while. How can you *guess* path? How do you know where it comes from?

Comment: I think you are asking how to execute some code after an image is loaded from the database?  If so, take a look at the doctrine event system and in particular the postLoad event. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: pogeybait, -1 for not "Writing a title that summarizes the specific problem". Please see the link [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details. In particular, when users are searching for a similar question, it is important to have the correct title. Can you edit your post and modify the title? Also, DQL is not the same as query builder! Can you confirm whether you are using [VichUploaderBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html) or not? Thanks!

Comment: @Cerad Yes, that is what Im asking

Comment: @AlvinBunk being new to Symfony and Doctrine, I dont know how to word my question(s) exactly right because both use different terminology that I am used to. All I can tell you is that to avoid the lazy query loading or whatever its called I created a method in a repository where I am using createQueryBuilder() to build a query. It runs fine but in Twig templates I can only refer to the fields I SELECTed in my createQueryBuilder. Since I am getting the image name and know where the site was crawled from, my fix currently is to modify the array index for the image and pre-append a path.

Comment: Also @AlvinBunk, "QueryBuilder helper methods are considered the standard way to build DQL queries." http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

if path is static, doctrine has nothing to do with your problem, you can use a constant or a parameter to define it.

then you jsut have to add a getter

```
getImageWebPath() {
   return self::PRODUCT_WEB_PATH. $this->getImageName();
}
```

If the image is stored in a parameter you can use a lot of tools: twig function wich append the path before your image name, services wich set the path to your entity or directly getting twig parameter... etc

Comment: Im using createQueryBuilder() which hydrates using reflection (not my words) so getters are not used and cause errors in Twig if I try to use anything other than the fields I selected in the select() clause.